# Setting param attribute explicitly, not updating with update_attributes call

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My controller calls this model method on update:

```
def update_standard(param_attributes)

...

if param_attributes[:is_legacy] == true
  param_attributes[:foo_type_id] = 2
end

  update_attributes(param_attributes)

end
```

`foo_type_id` should overwrite whatever the user entered in the form, but the user's choice is what is written to the DB.  How can I enforce `foo_type_id` being 2 when `is_legacy` is true?

Comment: You should check to make sure that `params[:is_legacy]` actually returns `true` and not `"true"` -- pretty sure params are always strings.

Comment: That worked.  If you'd like, enter your suggestion as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check to make sure that `params[:is_legacy]` actually returns `true` and not `"true"` -- pretty sure params are always strings.

Answer (score 2):

```
param_attributes[:is_legacy] == "true" ? param_attributes[:foo_type_id] = 2 : param_attributes[:foo_type_id]
update_attributes(param_attributes)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there could be some issues with your logic evaluation.

Try changing this to the following and see if it works?

```
if !param_attributes[:is_legacy].nil? && param_attributes[:is_legacy].to_sym == :true
  param_attributes[:foo_type_id] = 2
end
```